# Mobile safari issue with optgroups inside a select

Tags: safari, ios6, multiple-select, optgroup

Mobile Safari app on iOS 6 appears to have an issue with `<optgroup>` elements inside a `<select multiple="multiple">` element. I've [created a demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpuHU/) that works fine in iOS 5 Safari but appears not to work on iOS 6. I'm using html from [the second w3c example on this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H85.html#H85-examples) for the demo so I think it should be valid but I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing in the formatting and if the best workaround in the meantime is:

```
<option disabled="disabled">Option Group Label</option>
```

Comment: An example of the [demo redone using the workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/XauJ7/).

Comment: Apple is aware of the issue and there's another report filed over on [open radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/12467517)

Comment: Thankfully this issue appears to have been resolved in the recent update to iOS 6.1 (released Jan. 29, 2013).

Comment: This has partly been fixed in 7.1, however, you can now select your optgroup tiles which is totally wrong and it still crashes on selection of the first optgroup haha.  I have opened a bug reporter with Apple - #16272007